# How to convert regexp from lookahead

Tags: regex, go

I have the following Regex in PHP and other code that is doing a great job.

```
/^(?:(?=[^ ]+\d)(?:[A-Z0-9]+))|(?:[A-Z0-9]+) +?(?=.*\d)(?:[A-Z0-9]+)?
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/dKpoZrNfcdwtzOtR)

It turns out that Go doesn't support lookheads and I'm at a loss on how to convert it across.

The Debuggex link has some test data I was using to qualify the code before.

Comment: If you could provide *exact* specs for the regular expression, it would be easier to help you. Right now, it is not clear if you need the digit to be part of the match, or just require them to be somewhere after the expected match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the left hand side of the alternation `/^...` matches nothing, because `/` can never appear before start of input.

That leaves just `(?:[A-Z0-9]+) +?(?=.*\d)`, which can be expressed as:

```
((?:[A-Z0-9]+) ).*\d.*
```

The term `" +?"` as used is identical in effect to just `" "`.

Note however that this consumes more input than the original, which is unavoidable. Your original match is now in group 1.